# How to pass a pointer to a variable to the S3 progress function callback?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I know I can use something similar to this to monitor the progress of a object download

```
using (var response = client.GetObject(request)) 
{ 
    response.WriteObjectProgressEvent += Response_WriteObjectProgressEvent; 
    response.WriteResponseStreamToFile(@"C:\Downloads\file.exe"); 
} 

private static void Response_WriteObjectProgressEvent(object sender, WriteObjectProgressArgs e) 
{ 
    Debug.WriteLine($"Transfered: {e.TransferredBytes}/{e.TotalBytes} - Progress: {e.PercentDone}%"); 
}
```

However, I would like to save to e.PercentDone value into a specific variable.

How can I pass a pointer to this variable to the callback function ?

Thanks

Comment: Tag: C++ or C#?

Comment: Would the [ref keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) help you out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the example provided was C# code when my question was related to C++.

I finally solved my issue by passing my pointer defined as

> int *download_percentage;

to downloadProgressCallback() this way :

```
    transferConfig.downloadProgressCallback =
        [download_percentage](const Aws::Transfer::TransferManager *,
                           const std::shared_ptr<const Aws::Transfer::TransferHandle> &transferHandle) {
            if (download_percentage != NULL) {
                int percentage = *download_percentage;

                if (percentage !=
                    ((int)(((float)transferHandle->GetBytesTransferred() / transferHandle->GetBytesTotalSize()) *
                           100))) {
                    percentage =
                        (int)(((float)transferHandle->GetBytesTransferred() / transferHandle->GetBytesTotalSize()) *
                              100);
                    std::cout << "Download Progress: " << percentage << "%\n";

                    *download_percentage = percentage;
                }
            }
        };
```